# Using COUNTIFS in Excel, check cells (containing formulas) that are empty

Tags: excel-formula

Good day.

In it's basic form, I need to count how many cells are empty.

Using the following below, I can count how many cells are empty.

**=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C,"<>")**

However, if the cells in column C contain formulas, it won't work.

After some googling, I found out that using SUMPRODUCT will get what I need

**=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(Sheet1!C:C)>0))**

Now, here's my problem.

I need to use that as a criteria inside a COUNTIFS function, but I don't know how to do that because it's referencing some ranges.

So just to make it simple, using COUNTIF or COUNTIFS function specifically, how can I pass a criteria that checks if cell (with formula) is empty.

This formula returns 0 but most likely I'm just not passing it properly as a criteria.

**=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C,SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(Sheet1!C:C)>0)))**

Happy for other ways to count cells (with formulas) which are empty, but I need to use it as a criteria for a COUNTIF/COUNTIFS function.

Thank you very much.

Comment: =COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C,"?*") or =COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C:C,"?*") the result is as same as  =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(Sheet1!C:C)>0))

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for.

Thank you very much.

Update: I'm trying to mark your reply as the correct answer but I don't see any button/link for that. Maybe because I'm a new contributor. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for, you were pretty close already.
Following the formula's you already found you can use them like:
`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C,"<>")-SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(Sheet1!C:C)>0))`
It will result in the count of cells that have a value/formula minus the count of cells that show a value (blank formula result is excluded).
The result is the count of cells that contain a formula with blank result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but not the answer I was looking for. I need to use it as a criteria for a COUNTIFS function.

Comment: Not sure what you're searching for than. Do you want the result cell by cell, or a total of cells containing formula's resulting in blanks? And what do you want to use COUNTIF on after having that result?